# JS: Check for parameter in URL then iterate a function with parameter as var

Tags: javascript, html

I've the following piece of code:

```
<div id="1" class="hide"> Text1 </div>
<div id="2" class="hide"> Text2 </div>
<div id="3" class="hide"> Text3 </div>
<div id="4" class="hide"> Text4 </div>
<div id="5" class="hide"> Text5 </div>
```

I want all those divs to be hidden by a function that will check:
-If the URL contains a parameter equal to the ID of one of the div
-Do this, for each of the div: thus check if the URL contains a parameter from 1 to 5.
-Hide all elements except the one with the ID matching the parameter. Only one parameter will be in the URL at the same time.

This is the function code, which is separate so that the function can be called by other links:

```
function showOne(id) {
$('.hide').not('#' + id).hide(); }
```

Here is the iteration loop, now I am not sure how to piece them together in this specific way I need any directions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 while (i<6) {  
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('i=yes') > -1)
    {
    showOne(i)
    }}
```

Comment: For starters, i+'=yes'

Answer (score 2):

You are not iterating `i` and you are checking for the string `"i=yes"` not `"1=yes"`

```
while (i<6) {  
    if (window.location.search.indexOf(i + '=yes') > -1)
    {
        showOne(i);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```